# error: Failed to establish TLS connection: underlying network error (Connection reset by peer)

Tags: rudder

I am using Centos 7.6.

When running `rudder agent update`, I get a TLS connection error. The web console is working, and the machine is registered.  However, there are no reports from the server.

Any suggestions on what could be causing this would be helpful.

```
$ sudo rudder agent update
error: Failed to establish TLS connection: underlying network error (Connection reset by peer)   
error: No suitable server found
error: Failed to establish TLS connection: underlying network error (Connection reset by peer)   
error: No suitable server found R:
*********************************************************************************
* rudder-agent could not get an updated configuration from the policy server.   *
* This can be caused by:                                                        *
*   * an agent key that has been changed                                        *
*   * if this node is not accepted or deleted node on the Rudder root server    *
*   * if this node has changed policy server without sending a new inventory    *
* Any existing configuration policy will continue to be applied without change. *
********************************************************************************* 
error: Rudder agent promises could not be updated.
```

Answer (score 0):

To debug the problem, you can use `rudder server debug <NODE-IP-OR-HOSTNAME>` on your Rudder server (with the ip or hostname of the failing node as parameter), it will start a debug server and display more information about the connection.

Then run `rudder agent update` on the node and check the output on the server, it should indicate the cause of the problem. If you see nothing on the server, it is probably a network configuration issue, you need to check if tcp/5309 is correctly open from your node to the Rudder server.

*Note:* On the other hand, if the policy updates succeeds in debug mode (and only in debug mode), the problem probably lies in the policy server daemon on your Rudder server, and `rudder agent restart` on you Rudder server should fix it.

Comment: error: Remote host '10.......' not in allowconnects, denying connection

Comment: the actual ip address is stating "not in allowconnects"

Comment: You should check your allowed networks (https://docs.rudder.io/reference/5.0/administration/server.html#_configure_allowed_networks) in *Settings -> General*, to see if there is an IP range that matches your node, if not you need to add one.

Comment: that was it,  I had to use the netmask from the source machine, where I had 10.0.0.0/24 and expected it to match all 10.  address.